# non-blocking task.Wait in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

```
Task t = Task.Run(async () => { await someAsyncMethod(); });
t.Wait();
```

Does this mean that while `t.Wait()` is waiting, the thread is used for something else and not just sitting there waiting for the task to finish? Just because I used `async () => { await someAsyncMethod(); }`?

Comment: The opposite: The current thread will *block* while the task completes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Wait` will block the calling thread.

To do a non-blocking wait, use `await`:

```
await Task.Run(async () => { await someAsyncMethod(); });
```

However, `Task.Run` should generally only be used for CPU-bound methods, so it's more likely you can just do this:

```
await someAsyncMethod();
```

Comment: I see, but if the method that this code is running is not async, I can't use await. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: @some_guy You were calling `await` on it in your code, inside of the task, so clearly it was already asynchronous.  If the method really is a synchronous CPU bound method *then* `Task.Run` would be appropriate.

Comment: What I meant is, the method that holds the code that I posted is not async, but someAsyncMethod() it is async.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem and used:

```
var t = Task.Run(async () => { await someAsyncMethod(); });
t.Result;
```

This seems not to block the thread.

Comment: what about   t.ContinueWith((t) => result = t.Result)); ?

Comment: That doesn't compile.  What's `result`?

Comment: A more complete version would be something like this   public SomeType MethodThatIsNotAsync()
{
 SomeType result = default(SomeType);
 var t= Task.Run<SomeType>(async () => await SomeMethodCall());
 t.ContinueWith((t1) => result = t.Result);
 return result;
}

public SomeType SomeMethodCall()
{
 // do something
 return default(SomeType);
}

Comment: In that case you return the default value 100% of the time.  You never ever return the actual result